# Spring Data Mongodb Extracting Parts of a Sub-Documents

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring-data-mongodb 1.9.1.

My question is pretty similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730370/spring-data-mongodb-findby-method-for-nested-objects).

I have

```
@Document
 public class Employee{

 private int userId;
 private List<Address> addresses;
 }
```

And

```
@Document
public class Address{

 private int addressId;
 private String street;
 private String city:
 }
// Getters and setters
```

I have written a query and can get the value I need returned as an Employee object.

```
 @Query(value="{ '$and' : [ {'addresses.city' : ?0 }]} ", fields="{ 'addresses.street' : 1}")
    List<Employee> findStreetByEmployeeId(String fieldName);
```

My question is how can I get

List<**String**> findStreetByEmployeeId(String fieldName);

In other words, I want to just extract the part of the result in which I am interested. 
If I have to loop through all Employee objects and extract the populated street value, it can become a very expensive operation.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this would be much appreciated. Thanks.