# Spring data Find by list element

Tags: kotlin, spring-data, repository, spring-data-jpa

I would like to ask if its possible to write Spring JPA method in repo avoiding SQL and @Query. This method have to return list which joined list value is equal to something.

This is class:

```
class Temp1{
 val a: String,
}
```

This is class that contains above class:

```
class Temp{
val aSet: Set<Temp1>
}
```

And so I would like to have method in repo that return every Temp which aSet "a" value is equal to string.

I've got now: `findByaSetIn(aSet: List<Temp>)` but it requires list of Temp values instead of more precisly "a" value.

In sql its something similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM Temp t JOIN Temp1 t1 ON t1.tempID = t.id WHERE t1.a = "abc"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring data - Mongodb - findBy Method for nested objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730370/spring-data-mongodb-findby-method-for-nested-objects)

Comment: refer to https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions for how to query nested values

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is `Containing`.

In your example it should be like this:

```
findByASetContaining(item :Temp1)
```

The method will return a collection of all "Temp" entities where the "aSet" contains the entity "item".

You can use `Containing` not only for the search in lists and sets, it works also for  the search in string values.

Comment: Sweet. Worked perfectly!